# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{1}-\frac{1}{2\pi }\ln(\left \| x-y \right \|)\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I came across the integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}-\frac{1}{2\pi }ln(\sqrt{(r\cdot\cos(2\pi t_{x})-r\cdot \cos(2\pi t_{y}))^{2}+(r\cdot\sin(2\pi t_{x})-r\cdot\sin(2\pi t_{y}))^{2}})\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$
with $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$ but wasn't able to calculate it so far.

I already know and can use that $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(\sin(\pi t))\sin(2\pi kt)dt=0$$ and $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(\sin(\pi t))\cos(2\pi kt)dt=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-\ln(2), k=0\\ 
-\dfrac{1}{2k},k\geq 1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I also know that the result should be something like $$\lambda _k\cdot e^{i2\pi kt},k\in \mathbb{N}_0$$

I tried to use several trigonometric identities but did not succeed.

Comment: I should say that I use polar coordinates for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clean some things up:

$$-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}ln{[(r\cdot cos(2\pi t_{x})-r\cdot cos(2\pi t_{y}))^{2}+(r\cdot sin(2\pi t_{x})-r\cdot sin(2\pi t_{y}))^{2}}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+ln{[(cos(2\pi t_{x})- cos(2\pi t_{y}))^{2}+(sin(2\pi t_{x})-sin(2\pi t_{y}))^{2}}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+ln{[cos^2(2\pi t_{x})- 2cos(2\pi t_{x})cos(2\pi t_{y})+ cos^2(2\pi t_{y})+sin^2(2\pi t_{x})- 2sin(2\pi t_{x})sin(2\pi t_{y})+ sin^2(2\pi t_{y})}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+ln{[2- 2cos(2\pi t_{x})cos(2\pi t_{y})- 2sin(2\pi t_{x})sin(2\pi t_{y})}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+ln2+ln{[1- cos(2\pi t_{x})cos(2\pi t_{y})- sin(2\pi t_{x})sin(2\pi t_{y})}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

Then we use some trigonometric identities:

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+ln2+ln{[1- cos2(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+ln2+ln{[2cos^2(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+2ln2+2ln{[cos(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+2ln2+2ln0.5+2ln{[e^{i(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})})+e^{-i(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})}}]\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

Things should be much easier to solve from here. :)

EDIT: Next part of the solution:

$$=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2lnr+2ln2+2ln0.5+2i(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y}){{+2ln[1+e^{-2i(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})}}]}\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}lnr+ln2+ln0.5+i\pi t_{x}-i\pi t_{y}{{+ln[1+e^{-2i(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})}}]}\cdot e^{i2\pi kt_{x}}dt_{x}$$

Using the fact that $\int e^x(ln(1+e^x))dx=(e^x+1)ln(1+e^x)-e^x+C$,

$$=-\frac{1}{2\pi }[t_{x}(lnr+ln2+ln0.5-i\pi t_{y} )+\frac{i\pi (t_{x})^2}{2}+e^\frac{-1}{k}(1+e^{-2i(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})})ln(1+e^{-2i(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})})-e^\frac{-1}{k}e^{-2i(\pi t_{x}-\pi t_{y})}]_{0}^{1}$$

And lo and behold:

$$=[lnr+ln2+ln0.5-i\pi t_{y} )+\frac{i\pi}{2}+e^\frac{-1}{k}(1+e^{-2i(\pi-\pi t_{y})})ln(1+e^{-2i(\pi -\pi t_{y})})-e^\frac{-1}{k}e^{-2i(\pi-\pi t_{y})}]-[e^\frac{-1}{k}(1+e^{2i\pi t_{y}}ln(1+e^{2i\pi t_{y}})-e^\frac{-1}{k}e^{2i\pi t_{y}}]$$

Apologies if I've made any errors, the working is just too chaotic for me. :P

Comment: Thank you so far. I cancelled at a similar spot but I still don't understand how to calculate the difficult part of the integral in your last equation. Besides I'm not able to use the two hints in my post. I'm not committed to use them but at the moment they are my only ray of hope.

Comment: ^ See my edited post